# Error when declaring vector as a class data member

Tags: c++, vector, types

I am still wondering why an error message keeps on appearing 
when trying to declare a vector:

"Unknown type name 'setSize'"

```
#ifndef INTEGERSET_H
#define INTEGERSET_H

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class IntegerSet
{
public:
    IntegerSet();
    IntegerSet(const int [], const int);
    IntegerSet & unionOfSets(const IntegerSet &, const IntegerSet &) const;
    IntegerSet & intersectionOfSets(const IntegerSet &, const IntegerSet &) const;
    void insertElement(int);
    void deleteElement(int);
    void printSet();
    bool isEqualTo(const IntegerSet &);

    const int setSize = 10;
    vector<bool> set(setSize);

};



#endif
```

PS : I had to add 4 spaces to every line in order to copy and paste the above code, because it all went out of format. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Concerning your PS: Just  paste the code, highlight it, then press Ctrl+K.

Comment: i donot understand this fad about initialising in class declaration...this is what java developers do...why not use the initializer list/constructor??

Comment: @basav It can save you typing and reduce scope for errors if you have many constructors. I wouldn't call it a "fad" either. It is a pretty useful feature of the language.

Comment: agreed about the advantages..but they are not huge advantages and confusing when you have a really old code base, parts of which were written keeping old conventions..agreed with the fad part..i went a little overboard there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is parsed as a function declaration:

```
vector<bool> set(setSize); // function `set`, argument type `setSize`
```

You need a different initialization syntax:

```
vector<bool> set = vector<bool>(setSize);
```

---

Also note that giving things names such as `set` while `using namespace std;` is a very bad idea. [`using namespace std;` is a bad idea in most cases anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Alternatively you can use uniform initialization: `vector<bool> set { size }`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot That could result in a size 1 vector with the single element set to `true`.